# Setting state from selected value in react searchbar

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am new to react, and I apologize in advance if this seems overly simple.
I am using [react-select](https://react-select.com/home) to create a search bar. I am using functional components with react hooks per the requirements of the project. I am currently reading values from an API and loading up a dropdown list with those values. What I would like to do next is use the context API to take the selection from the dropdown and use the value in other components, but currently as it is implemented I don't seem to have access to the selected value in my dropdown. Here is a look at the code.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';
import GetData from '../../api';

function SearchBar() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    setData(
      GetData().map((DataObject) => (
        {
          value: DataObject.id,
          label: DataObject.name,
        }
      )),
    );
  },
  []);

  return <Select options={data} />;
}

export default SearchBar;
```

I have tried to get the value as suggested below as follows but data and its properties are undefined.

```
  return <Select options={data} onChange={() => alert(data.value)} />;
```

I think what I need to do is set another state variable for the selected value, but is this best practice. I have tried to implement this, but I don't seem to have access to the data.value or data.label? What is the best way to get the selected value into state so that I can then pass it into context? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried passing an `onChange` callback to the `Select`? You should be able to get the value from there.

Comment: GetData seems to be asynchronous. If it is asynchronous, you would have to set the state with data after the promise has resolved successfully

Comment: I have tried passing an onChange to the select as follows: return <Select options={data} onChange={() => alert(data.value)} />; but it data.value and data.id etc is undefined.

Comment: @rash.tay the values load initially from the API. I want to get the selected value.

Comment: @Camilo I updated the code above to indicate that I have tried the suggested approach.

Comment: @00robinette can you print `data` state value? I think there is a problem here.

Comment: You need to add `data` as a parameter for the callback function. Actually, I think you should rename it to something else since you already had declared `data`.

Comment: @superdev1994 It is undefined. If I try to print the values or console.log them in onChange. The dropdown is properly loaded with values, the problem is I have no idea to grab the id of the selected dropdown value.

Comment: @Camilo you can try to print GetData() result in the hook. I guess this function is asynchronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Select` has an `onChange` prop which you can pass a callback. The callback will received the new selected option as a parameter, so you could simply:

```
<Select
  options={data}
  onChange={(selectedOption) => {
    console.log(selectedOption);
    // Do something with selectedOption...
  }}
/>
```

Comment: This is better than what I posted above. Thanks!

Comment: Select it as your accepted answer so it's more clear for other users :)

Answer (score 0):

The following does the trick!

```
  return <Select options={data} onChange={(value) => alert(value.value)} />;
```